# RabbitMQ not receiving messages from remote server

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am able to get connect with the rabbitmQ deployed on my remote server. When I send a message from my python code running in local host works fine, Rabbit MQ Queue receives the message, However when I put my code(python) on to the server not receiving messages in queue.

Comment: Please check, whether RabbitMQ server is running on your server or not

Comment: This could be anything for server configuration to rabbit configuration. Some more details would be nice. Also, if you are unsure on the rabbitmq end, there is the option to install it with an addon called "management"  which sets up a dashboard to help you visually verify messages get to there.

Comment: RabbitMQ is up and showing available connection with the IP address (socket connection)

Comment: Please refer https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html